# Cancel an option used in aliased command?

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

Suppose for example, the following implementation of `ll`:

```
alias ls="ls -F -G"         # colourise and display dir,exec,etc. icons
alias ll="ls -l -h -o"      # long-list, use KB,MB,etc. sizes, no group id
```

Now suppose I use `ll`, and while usually I'm glad for the lack of (what is usually) clutter, I actually want the group IDs.

Is there any way of 'cancelling' an option, for example something like `ll -!o`?

More simply put, but without obvious use case, a command like `!` here that renders `foo -B -!B` equivalent to `foo`?

Tagged [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) because that's what I use, but if a portable solution does exist obviously (?) that's preferred.

Comment: Cumbersome workaround: You could do `C-x a` to expand the alias under the cursor, and then delete the unwanted options.

Comment: @muru Do you know how to do that in vi-mode?

Comment: I have `bindkey -v` in my `.zshrc`, so presumably I'm in Vi mode, and `C-x a` works for me.

Comment: @muru Oh I thought `C-x` was the emacs-mode equivalent of `<esc>` (where obviously `a` in vi-mode takes us back to insert mode)

Comment: @muru It just types the character `a` or `^A` when I try this (according to whether or not I'm still holding ctrl). If in normal mode then `C-x` seems to have no affect, and `a` takes me back to insert. What have I got wrong?

Comment: Check if you have bound it to something.

Comment: @muru No bindings at all in my, or `/etc`s zshrc. Still doesn't work in `exec /bin/zsh -f` or `exec /usr/local/bin/zsh -f` - versions zsh `5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)` and `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)` respectively.

Comment: I do get a bell though.

Comment: Something to do with your terminal, I suppose. Or whatever you might have in `TERM` Not a Mac user, so no idea. :/

Comment: `TERM=xterm-256color`, I have tried two terminal applications (Terminal.app and iTerm2) :/ thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `ls` and some others commands you can add another option(s) which will negate those existing in an alias.

But as a *general* solution I think the best approach is the following:

- write an aliased command (do not put space after command)
- run a widget *_expand_alias* (`M-x _expand_alias`)
- remove unnecessary options and hit enter

You can bind this widget to some key (`^Xa` by default) if you need this procedure frequently.

Comment: I don't think `-o` can be negated.

Comment: As discussion above, for some reason `C-x` and `M-x` are having no effect. However, if I `bindkey '\C-x\C-a' '\M-x _expand_alias'` then I get "No such widget".

Comment: @Ollie Ford What do you see after `zle -la | grep expand | grep alias`? Oh, and you should of course run `bindkey '\C-x\C-a' '_expand_alias'`, without `\M-x` - this is not a widget name, but a command bindings (`meta`/`alt` - `x`).

Comment: I did, but then it says "No such shell function _expand_alias". Grep output is "_expand_alias".

Comment: @OllieFord This widget needs to be activated via `autoload -U compinit && compinit`, but if `zle -la` sees it then it should work.  What do you see if you start new shell with `zsh -f` and then just run `_expand_alias`?

Comment: @jimmij Ah - thanks. I think it showed up because I naïvely `autoload`ed itself rather than `compinit`. Thanks!